# How much does the market cap increase when a certain amount of $'s go in the market?

Tags: exchange-rate, market

Lets say that $1B worth of money is going in to bitcoin and its current market cap is $100B. How much would the market cap increase with that $1B?

Would it go to $101B, $105B, $110B, $100.1B?

I know that it will change according to how the money is put in. If they find someone selling by hand locally than it wouldn't affect the market price/market cap at all.

But I'm more curious on the average of the increase? I'm guessing there is a formula for it in finance? What is it?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean exactly. When you say "$1B worth of money is going in to bitcoin", do you mean that some bitcoins change hands for $1B? If so, why should that push the price up rather than down? Every time someone buys, someone else sells, right?

Answer (score 2):

Given that the Bitcoin market is pretty unstable + unregulated I don't think it is possible to predict the outcome of this.

Have a look at the paper *Price Manipulation in the Bitcoin Ecosystem* by *Neil Gandal et al.* to get an idea of why this is very hard (if not impossible) to predict.

Comment: Maybe it is, so is there a formula for similar assets?